# Adding base url to an html.erb only for img tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

This is for an ROR app deployed on domain1. The images displayed on a html page need to be served from domain2.

The image tags are defined with a relative path. To fix this I added a base tag  in the html file's  tag.

The problem is that the base url is getting appended to javascripts(on the page) under assets as well. I want the js file paths to be as it is. I want to just add the base url to the img tags.

How do I proceed on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use html "img" tag directly instead of using rails image_tag helper.

One example for "img":

```
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42"   
    width="42">
```

The src of image above is an absolute url from another site.